# Externalize config (password, connectionString) in UWP

Tags: config, windows-10, uwp

I'm looking for a way to externalize some config in an UWP application. 
The application need to connect to an Alfresco Server. And I want the user to be able to configure the Login, Password, and the url of the server.

I tried to put an xml file in my assets file, but when the App is installed, it's locate in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps, and the user can't have an easy access to it.

Is there any way to acheiev this like with an app.config file ?

Comment: How about provide an UI in your app to set the required data?

Comment: The problem with this is that each user that install the app gonna need to setup the required data.

Comment: "And I want the user to be able to configure the Login, Password, and the url of the server." - Provide a default value, and give the user the option to configure it. Save the configuration in your app folder and you're fine.

Comment: Thanks Herdo, i'll do something like that !!

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to use a known StorageFolder like :

```
KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary
```

If you add a file type association into you manifest (Package.appxmanifest > Declarations > File Type Associations) for a particular extension (like .config), your app can read files of this type in the document folder. Users can edit theses files manualy too.

Note all files you include in your assets (in your package) are read-only files.

Another way if your users are experienced : they can edit a file in the local storage (with no need to make a file association into your manifest). In this case, you use the following StorageFolder :

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
```

And users can edit files into a specifique directory :

```
C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Packages\<AppId>\AppData
```

Comment: The problem is that the <AppId> is not really user friendly

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue where I needed to use an external file that is not tracked by source control. There are two ways to access data from resource or configuration files.

One is to open and parse a configuration file. Given a file `sample.txt` with **Build Action** `Content` (**Copy to Output Directory** doesn't matter), we can read it with

```
var uri = new System.Uri("ms-appx:///sample.txt");
var sampleFile = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
```

or

```
var packageFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
var sampleFile = await packageFolder.GetFileAsync("sample.txt");
```

followed by

```
var contents = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile);
```

Alternatively, we can use **Resources**. Add a new Resource item to the project, called `resourcesFile.resw`. To access data, use:

```
var resources = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader("resourcesFile");
var token = resources.GetString("secret");
```

I wrote more verbose answer in a blog post [Custom resource files in UWP](http://amadeusw.com/iot/custom-resource-files-in-uwp-windows-10/)

Comment: the link you provided is invalid

Comment: Also, in your proposed solutions, where would the user modify the files?

Comment: var packageFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
var sampleFile = await packageFolder.CreateFileAsync("sample.txt");

Throws System.UnauthorizedAccessException